# Get selected word documents from user's choice and merge those documents as a single doc file

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word

We have 15 word docx files stored in c:\docs folder named *"a1.docx, a2.docx, a3.docx...a15.dox "* I have created a word file to get user's choice through 15 checkboxes displayed (with file name).

I have named the bookmark of each checkbox as *"a1, a2, a3...a15".* The user may select any 2 or more documents from the list of documents displayed by ticking the check box.

Can anybody help with a macro to **merge** **selected documents only** in the current document itself?

Searching the net, got sample vba code to merge all the documents in a particular folder as a single file.

I want to merge only selected documents from the list.

This is the code I use to get user feedback and merge the selected documents in the current document location one by one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Const strPath As String = "C:\Docs\"
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Selection.InsertBreak
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:=strPath & "a1.docx", Range:="", ConfirmConversions:= _
    False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
End If
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
   Selection.InsertBreak
   Selection.InsertFile FileName:=strPath & "a2.docx", Range:="", ConfirmConversions:= _
   False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
End If
Me.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: Try isolating the code that copies from a single source file to the destination file, into a separate procedure which takes the source path as a parameter. Then you can call this procedure on each selected item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear if you want to have the selected content in the currently open file or in a new file, but the following will work in principle in either case. I have done something similar with inserting contents into templates from a source file where each file is opened, the content copied and then pasted into the new file.

For each of the checkboxes you will need to do the following:

```
Documents.Open(FilePath & CheckboxName & ".docx").Activate
    ActiveDocument.Range.Select 
    Selection.Copy                                   'selects all and copies
'Activate the file you want to paste it into     
    Documents(FilePath & FileName).Activate
    Selection.Paste
    Selection.InsertBreak
'close the original document    
    Documents(FilePath & CheckboxName & ".docx").Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
```